# How to check Webflux stream into Postman

Tags: postman, spring-webflux

I have created webflux app and it's generating stream.

```
@GetMapping(value = "/stream/tweets", produces = MediaType.TEXT_EVENT_STREAM_VALUE)
    public Flux<Tweet> streamAllTweets() {
        return tweetRepository.findAll();
    }
```

Now issue is that contentType "text/event-stream" is not supported into Postman and not able to see stream without refresh.

How to check stream in postman or any other tools

[image]

Comment: you can just use a browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please use Content-Type: "**application/stream+json**" instead of "text/event-stream" in the postman headers.